# Large import files under pub/media taking too much space

Tags: magento2, aws

I have worked on Magento before but haven't done anything related to imports, so a new problem arised were the disk of the AWS instance is getting used up due to large files in `pub/media/import`

[image]

You can see the folders img-old, img-old2 contains a lot of large images and zip files which I believe were imported at some point.

I would like to know how it would affect the site if I remove the imported files? Are these files used at any places in the site and the catalog itself?